# Plotly Choropleth Map not populating

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, choropleth

I'm trying to create a Choropleth map of Users per state, but it's blank and I'm not sure what's going on.

[My data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjBA7.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px


data = pd.read_csv('geographic_analytics.csv')

fig = px.choropleth(data,
                    locations='state',
                    color='Users',
                    locationmode='USA-states',
                    scope='usa',
                    color_continuous_scale='Viridis')



fig.show()
```

[The map that appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chqeg.png)

I added the state column so that Plotly could read the state data, the legend appears correctly, but I can't figure out why it's not populating on the map. I also checked the dtype of the column "Users," and they are integers. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my data, sorry it's my first post.

| state | Region | Country | Users | New users | Engaged sessions | Engagement rate | Engaged sessions per user | Average engagement time | Event count | Conversions | Total revenue | latitude | longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TX | Texas | United States | 11495 | 10106 | 9981 | 0.575207469 | 0.868290561 | 144.569726 | 130879 | 0 | 0 | 31.968599 | -99.901813 |
| FL | Florida | United States | 8477 | 7390 | 8344 | 0.593583268 | 0.984310487 | 171.6410287 | 113018 | 0 | 0 | 27.664827 | -81.515754 |
| VA | Virginia | United States | 7410 | 6367 | 4533 | 0.451359156 | 0.611740891 | 92.10850202 | 61600 | 0 | 0 | 37.431573 | -78.656894 |
| GA | Georgia | United States | 7229 | 5978 | 5552 | 0.529770992 | 0.768017706 | 127.1543782 | 75569 | 0 | 0 | 32.157435 | -82.907123 |
| IL | Illinois | United States | 5753 | 4933 | 4594 | 0.564998155 | 0.798539892 | 111.4573266 | 57718 | 0 | 0 | 40.633125 | -89.398528 |
| OH | Ohio | United States | 5204 | 4294 | 4297 | 0.570272064 | 0.825710992 | 130.5009608 | 55680 | 0 | 0 | 40.417287 | -82.907123 |
| CA | California | United States | 5094 | 4621 | 3563 | 0.538787237 | 0.699450334 | 100.3678838 | 42409 | 0 | 0 | 36.778261 | -119.417932 |
| PA | Pennsylvania | United States | 5031 | 4338 | 4712 | 0.592331867 | 0.936593123 | 149.0725502 | 61288 | 0 | 0 | 41.203322 | -77.194525 |
| NC | North Carolina | United States | 4966 | 4086 | 4415 | 0.570634613 | 0.889045509 | 138.6526379 | 56354 | 0 | 0 | 35.759573 | -79.0193 |
| MI | Michigan | United States | 4540 | 3649 | 3792 | 0.560532151 | 0.835242291 | 137.3475771 | 50925 | 0 | 0 | 44.314844 | -85.602364 |
| NY | New York | United States | 4107 | 3333 | 2766 | 0.513458326 | 0.673484295 | 92.3523253 | 34541 | 0 | 0 | 43.299428 | -74.217933 |
| AZ | Arizona | United States | 3998 | 3524 | 3704 | 0.555072681 | 0.926463232 | 152.4877439 | 49801 | 0 | 0 | 34.048928 | -111.093731 |
| WA | Washington | United States | 3716 | 3391 | 3050 | 0.566703828 | 0.820775027 | 140.8877826 | 42742 | 0 | 0 | 47.751074 | -120.740139 |
| IN | Indiana | United States | 3293 | 2571 | 2615 | 0.547300126 | 0.794108715 | 135.1876708 | 35712 | 0 | 0 | 40.551217 | -85.602364 |
| TN | Tennessee | United States | 3241 | 2563 | 2723 | 0.566819317 | 0.840172786 | 140.5828448 | 37603 | 0 | 0 | 35.517491 | -86.580447 |
| CO | Colorado | United States | 3205 | 2769 | 2700 | 0.560514843 | 0.842433697 | 136.5391576 | 36475 | 0 | 0 | 39.550051 | -105.782067 |
| MO | Missouri | United States | 3045 | 2474 | 2639 | 0.583333333 | 0.866666667 | 156.7632184 | 35747 | 0 | 0 | 37.964253 | -91.831833 |
| WI | Wisconsin | United States | 2680 | 2190 | 2358 | 0.569290198 | 0.879850746 | 136.1320896 | 29785 | 0 | 0 | 43.78444 | -88.787868 |
| SC | South Carolina | United States | 2163 | 1625 | 1741 | 0.565994798 | 0.804900601 | 142.9939898 | 22642 | 0 | 0 | 33.836081 | -81.163725 |
| MN | Minnesota | United States | 2125 | 1728 | 2049 | 0.591000865 | 0.964235294 | 170.8865882 | 30863 | 0 | 0 | 46.729553 | -94.6859 |
| IA | Iowa | United States | 2085 | 1549 | 1545 | 0.513801131 | 0.741007194 | 114.9223022 | 21043 | 0 | 0 | 41.878003 | -93.097702 |
| AL | Alabama | United States | 2004 | 1581 | 1598 | 0.573994253 | 0.79740519 | 149.9845309 | 21463 | 0 | 0 | 32.318231 | -86.902298 |
| KY | Kentucky | United States | 1933 | 1449 | 1365 | 0.538674033 | 0.706156234 | 116.9032592 | 17743 | 0 | 0 | 37.839333 | -84.270018 |
| OK | Oklahoma | United States | 1873 | 1441 | 1386 | 0.545454545 | 0.739989322 | 120.510945 | 18761 | 0 | 0 | 35.007752 | -97.092877 |
| OR | Oregon | United States | 1814 | 1553 | 1648 | 0.595160708 | 0.908489526 | 164.1400221 | 21682 | 0 | 0 | 43.804133 | -120.554201 |
| KS | Kansas | United States | 1702 | 1282 | 1193 | 0.528577758 | 0.700940071 | 144.0658049 | 16220 | 0 | 0 | 39.011902 | -98.484246 |
| UT | Utah | United States | 1466 | 1219 | 1273 | 0.582875458 | 0.86834925 | 149.7428377 | 18897 | 0 | 0 | 39.32098 | -111.093731 |
| LA | Louisiana | United States | 1411 | 1098 | 1188 | 0.571153846 | 0.84195606 | 155.6045358 | 16517 | 0 | 0 | 31.244823 | -92.145024 |
| AR | Arkansas | United States | 1382 | 1058 | 1017 | 0.547657512 | 0.735890014 | 116.4833575 | 13297 | 0 | 0 | 35.20105 | -91.831833 |
| MD | Maryland | United States | 1269 | 1079 | 1177 | 0.589974937 | 0.92750197 | 159.9014972 | 16294 | 0 | 0 | 39.045755 | -76.641271 |
| MA | Massachusetts | United States | 1251 | 1034 | 985 | 0.562535694 | 0.787370104 | 114.8417266 | 13046 | 0 | 0 | 42.407211 | -71.382437 |
| NE | Nebraska | United States | 1247 | 926 | 992 | 0.552031163 | 0.795509222 | 124.0649559 | 13574 | 0 | 0 | 41.492537 | -99.901813 |
| MS | Mississippi | United States | 1235 | 895 | 901 | 0.522318841 | 0.729554656 | 125.8834008 | 11384 | 0 | 0 | 32.354668 | -89.398528 |
| WV | West Virginia | United States | 1211 | 861 | 780 | 0.512483574 | 0.644095789 | 107.3641618 | 10441 | 0 | 0 | 38.597626 | -80.454903 |
| NV | Nevada | United States | 1162 | 991 | 1101 | 0.575535808 | 0.947504303 | 157.6437177 | 13861 | 0 | 0 | 38.80261 | -116.419389 |
| MT | Montana | United States | 1134 | 846 | 738 | 0.501358696 | 0.650793651 | 100.6402116 | 9732 | 0 | 0 | 46.879682 | -110.362566 |
| NM | New Mexico | United States | 1127 | 896 | 890 | 0.55764411 | 0.789707187 | 119.2191659 | 11106 | 0 | 0 | 34.97273 | -105.032363 |
| ID | Idaho | United States | 1097 | 850 | 873 | 0.580066445 | 0.795806746 | 118.7228806 | 10424 | 0 | 0 | 44.068202 | -114.742041 |
| NJ | New Jersey | United States | 1091 | 951 | 961 | 0.660935351 | 0.880843263 | 125.2969753 | 11089 | 0 | 0 | 40.058324 | -74.405661 |
| ME | Maine | United States | 1063 | 771 | 695 | 0.517498138 | 0.653809972 | 115.0084666 | 9245 | 0 | 0 | 45.253783 | -69.445469 |
| NH | New Hampshire | United States | 828 | 620 | 582 | 0.542404473 | 0.702898551 | 123.2210145 | 7522 | 0 | 0 | 43.193852 | -71.572395 |
| CT | Connecticut | United States | 749 | 571 | 584 | 0.525652565 | 0.779706275 | 123.6755674 | 7265 | 0 | 0 | 41.603221 | -73.087749 |
| WY | Wyoming | United States | 714 | 561 | 430 | 0.475138122 | 0.602240896 | 89.23109244 | 5846 | 0 | 0 | 43.075968 | -107.290284 |
| SD | South Dakota | United States | 600 | 429 | 424 | 0.515815085 | 0.706666667 | 123.3283333 | 5426 | 0 | 0 | 43.969515 | -99.901813 |
| ND | North Dakota | United States | 440 | 311 | 303 | 0.571698113 | 0.688636364 | 93.90227273 | 3977 | 0 | 0 | 47.551493 | -101.002012 |
| DE | Delaware | United States | 324 | 242 | 271 | 0.554192229 | 0.836419753 | 125.2561728 | 3205 | 0 | 0 | 38.910832 | -75.52767 |
| DC | District of Columbia | United States | 319 | 282 | 280 | 0.574948665 | 0.877742947 | 112.0940439 | 3608 | 0 | 0 | 38.905985 | -77.033418 |
| VT | Vermont | United States | 303 | 220 | 214 | 0.572192513 | 0.706270627 | 101.2970297 | 2420 | 0 | 0 | 44.558803 | -72.577841 |
| RI | Rhode Island | United States | 152 | 127 | 149 | 0.693023256 | 0.980263158 | 143.4276316 | 1912 | 0 | 0 | 41.580095 | -71.477429 |
| HI | Hawaii | United States | 99 | 95 | 76 | 0.571428571 | 0.767676768 | 115.4343434 | 910 | 0 | 0 | 19.898682 | -155.665857 |
| AK | Alaska | United States | 93 | 89 | 79 | 0.612403101 | 0.849462366 | 106.7096774 | 741 | 0 | 0 | 63.588753 | -154.493062 |

Comment: can you provide the actual data instead of a screenshot of it?

Comment: @OriYardenPhD I just added it. Thank you for taking the time to help :)

Answer (score 0):

What version of plotly are you using? I am using version `5.14.1`, and the choropleth map renders as expected.

```
fig = px.choropleth(data,
                    locations='state',
                    color='Users',
                    locationmode='USA-states',
                    scope='usa',
                    color_continuous_scale='Viridis')

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I was using the most recent version. I downgraded to your versions, but my map os still not populating.

Comment: probably a long shot, but what browser are you using?